# Как сделать проверку для Тг-бота? (Python, Aiogram, DateTime)

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, datetime

**Имеется следующий код:**

```
@dp.message_handler(text='Вчера')
async def btn_yesterday(message: types.Message):
    try:
        date = str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%d.%m.%Y'))
        link = f"https://mtkspb.ru/public/educational/schedule/Расписание%20{date}.pdf"
        response = requests.get(link) # отправка HTTP GET запроса на сайт
        # полученные данные сохраняются в PDF
        pdf = open("pdf.pdf", 'wb')
        pdf.write(response.content)
        pdf.close()
        file_path = "pdf.pdf" # путь к PDF файлу
        # дефолтные настройки
        dpi = 300
        zoom = dpi / 72
        magnify = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
        page = fitz.open(file_path)
        pix = page[0].get_pixmap(matrix=magnify) # 1-ая страница PDF преобразуется в пиксельную карту
        pix.save("page.png") # пиксельная карта сохраняется в формате .png
        img = open("page.png", 'rb')
        await message.answer_photo(photo=img, caption='@mtkspbbot')
    except:
        await message.answer('Ничего не найдено!')
```

---

Как сделать так, чтобы ссылка "искалась" в 2-ух форматах: '%d.%m.%Y' и '%d-%m-%Y', и если была найдена из двух '%d-%m-%Y', то бот бы скидывал картинку из неё. Если же была найдена только '%d.%m.%Y', то быт бы скидывал её. А если ничего не найдено, то бот бы, как и было, присылал текст 'Ничего не найдено!'?

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(text='Вчера')
async def btn_yesterday(message: types.Message):
    date1 = str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%d.%m.%Y'))
    date2 = str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%d-%m-%Y'))
    link1 = f"https://mtkspb.ru/public/educational/schedule/Расписание%20{date1}.pdf"
    link2 = f"https://mtkspb.ru/public/educational/schedule/Расписание%20{date2}.pdf"
    response1 = requests.get(link1) # отправка HTTP GET запроса на сайт
    response2 = requests.get(link2)  # отправка HTTP GET запроса на сайт
    if response1.status_code == 200 and response2.status_code == 200:
        # полученные данные сохраняются в PDF
        pdf = open("pdf.pdf", 'wb')
        pdf.write(response2.content)
        pdf.close()
        file_path = "pdf.pdf" # путь к PDF файлу
        # дефолтные настройки
        dpi = 300
        zoom = dpi / 72
        magnify = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
        page = fitz.open(file_path)
        pix = page[0].get_pixmap(matrix=magnify) # 1-ая страница PDF преобразуется в пиксельную карту
        pix.save("page.png") # пиксельная карта сохраняется в формате .png
        img = open("page.png", 'rb')
        await message.answer_photo(photo=img, caption='@mtkspbbot')
    elif response1.status_code == 200 and response2.status_code == 404:
        # полученные данные сохраняются в PDF
        pdf = open("pdf.pdf", 'wb')
        pdf.write(response1.content)
        pdf.close()
        file_path = "pdf.pdf"  # путь к PDF файлу
        # дефолтные настройки
        dpi = 300
        zoom = dpi / 72
        magnify = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
        page = fitz.open(file_path)
        pix = page[0].get_pixmap(matrix=magnify)  # 1-ая страница PDF преобразуется в пиксельную карту
        pix.save("page.png")  # пиксельная карта сохраняется в формате .png
        img = open("page.png", 'rb')
        await message.answer_photo(photo=img, caption='@mtkspbbot')
    else:
        await message.answer('Ничего не найдено!')
```